# Sending message on a transaction?

Tags: ether, dapp-development, ethereumjs

I want send a data on a transaction.
_data is storing my message..
Here's my code:

```js
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9ce80a86c6c54d22aa821d0486a1a47d')

var account1 = '0xa00c70B72150D627cf53872eefD077079116B6a6'
var account2 = '0xD2a8aa318Fbc56995Db8C415BE6E40329DB1C56C'

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1, 'hex')
var _data = '0x6d79206e616d65206973206872697368616268'

const privateKey2 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_2, 'hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
    const txObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        to: account2,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
        data: _data,
    }
    console.log(txObject)
    const tx = new Tx(txObject)
    tx.sign(privateKey1)

    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
        console.log(txHash)
    })
})
```

The transaction is processed successfully, But the input data message is not the _data value in the etherscan.io

Comment: I must have missed something... where is the "input data message" in your code?

Comment: Sorry mate,I posted the wrong snippet, now its fixed....

Comment: That code looks fine. Can you point to the transaction on etherscan?